# How to know if a Simulink name block already exist with Matlab

Tags: matlab, if-statement, simulink

I'm parsing a text file with matlab, creating a system for each tag [Component] i found and saving system. I would like to make a loop like this :

```
if SystemName already exist
    load_system
else 
    create_system
```

But i don't know how to do for the if line .
Thanks for help.

Comment: you can use the `exist()`-function of matlab: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exist.html

Comment: @Max and if i want to know if a block inside a Simulink system exist or not by his name i can do it with exist() function?

Comment: No. In that case you would have to use `Simulink.findBlocks()`